# Solr search query with multiple entities in single document

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a solr data config like below (using mysql db)

```
<document>
            <entity name="users"   
                    query="SELECT user_id, user_id as pk_field, user_name FROM users">                        
            </entity>                

            <entity name="group"   
                    query="SELECT group_id, group_id as pk_field, group_name FROM  groups">
            </entity>        
</document>
```

Now, I want to search it in solr based on entity name. In general if I search its retrieving from both the documents. I need to specify the entity name while searching. could some one please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the entity type as one of the values in your queries:

```
SELECT 'group' AS entity_type, group_id, group_id as pk_field, group_name ...
```

and

```
SELECT 'user' AS entity_type, user_id, user_id as pk_field, user_name
```

You can then append a `fq=entity_type:user` to only search through your users and `entity_type:group` to only search your groups.